# Creating complex nested dictionary from values pulled from csv file. - Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, parsing

I have the following files:

[Files](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3c93b06646ea1d06d9739d2bd0e6423720200223155104/b8b80f9c704bc0a128df4e55364661f120200223155104/21c3c5)

I need to be able to build a dictionary and populate it with data from the multiple csv files

Inside each file appears as follows:

[image]

So my problem is this I need to gather all the files in the directory loop through each one line by line and separate the relevant data out into the dictionary as shown.

Here is what I have so far - I am managing to loop through the directory and obtain each individual file name however I am unsure as to how to read each one line by line parsing out the data required as I go into the dictionary.

```
from glob import glob
import os
from os.path import basename
import csv
import numpy as np

def main():

    rts = {}

    directory = 'C:/Users/oli.warriner/Desktop/data(2)/data/'

    files = sorted(glob('C:/Users/oli.warriner/Desktop/data(2)/data/*.csv'))
    sfiles = [basename(filepath) for filepath in files]
    for f in sfiles:
        path = os.path.join(directory, f)
        singleFile = csv.DictReader(open(path, 'r'))
        for line in singleFile:
            if f not in rts:
                rts[f] = []
                if line['condition'] not in rts[f]:
                    rts[ line['condition']] = []

                rts[ line['condition']].append(float (line['rt']))

    for condition in rts.keys():
        data = np.array(rts[condition])
        m = data.mean()
        v = data.var()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Current Dictionary output:

```
{'congruent': [0.647259, 0.720116, 0.562909, 0.538918, 0.633367, 0.668142, 1.820112, 0.798532, 0.470939, ...],
'incongruent': [0.767041, 0.990185, 0.693017, 0.679368, 0.951432, 1.289047, 0.647722, 0.858307, 1.118404, ...]}
```

Desired Output:

```
results = {'PO1': 
        {'Congruent': 
            {'rt':  {0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6}},
            {'correct': {TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE}}
        },
        {'Incongruent': 
            {'rt':  {0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6}},
            {'correct': {TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE}}           
        }
       },
       {'PO2': 
        {'Congruent': 
            {'rt':  {0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6}},
            {'correct': {TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE}}
        },
        {'Incongruent': 
            {'rt':  {0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6}},
            {'correct': {TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE}}           
        }
       },
       {'PO3': 
        {'Congruent': 
            {'rt':  {0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6}},
            {'correct': {TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE}}
        },
        {'Incongruent': 
            {'rt':  {0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6}},
            {'correct': {TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE}}           
        }
       }
```

I need to be able to nest the rt values within each condition and the correct values for each condition. This also needs to be seperated by file and stored in the dictionary as well.

I will be using the dictionary calculate mean and stddev reaction times for each of the conditions.
Any help is greatly appreciated. If I have been too vague anywhere please don't hesitate to ask questions

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: If you are on Python 3.4+, consider replacing `os.path` and `glob` with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Your code will be shorter and more readable by using that.

Comment: @accdias Thanks for that tip. Any ideas on  the problem at hand? Im having trouble building up the complex dictionary

Comment: I need to be able to add more keys within each condition for 'rt' and 'correct' values as you can see above

Comment: What is the rule to generate `P01`, `P02` ... `P0n` keys? How do you decide what pairs of values will make `Congruent` and `Incongruent` keys for each `P0n`?

Comment: Nevermind. Just downloaded the sample files and I got it from there. Let me see if I can fix your code now.

Comment: @accdias I have updated my current code I am generating P01 etc keys like shwn I am just using the file name I could trim this if needed so I just get P01 as opposed to P01.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will populate the `rts` dictionary with the values you are expecting. I've left the `numpy` portion out on purpose though. I guess it will not be a problem for you to pick up from there.

It requires Python 3.4+ because of `pathlib`:

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path


def main():
    rts = {}

    data = Path('C:/Users/oli.warriner/Desktop/data(2)/data')

    for csvfile in data.glob('*.csv'):
        key = csvfile.stem

        with csvfile.open() as f:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(f)

            # Skip the header
            _ = next(csv_reader)

            rts[key] = {
                'congruent': {
                    'rt': [],
                    'correct': []
                },
                'incongruent': {
                    'rt': [],
                    'correct': []
                },
            }

            for tn, ctext, cname, condition, response, rt, correct in csv_reader:
                rts[key][condition]['rt'].append(float(rt))
                rts[key][condition]['correct'].append(correct)
```

I hope it helps as a starting point.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for your help with this! That's a really nice clean way of building the dictionary. I can process the statistics I need from here. Thanks again!

Comment: I edited the code and removed `defaultdict` since a simple `dict` will do the job. I also removed `title()` from `condition` and make `rts` keys lowercase, assuming all `condition` from CSV files are lowercase. That will save a little bit of memory.